# Работа с SendMessage - C++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, sendmessage

Как отобразить в sendmessage координаты курсора(рабочей области окна) и на каком пункте меню находится курсор в данный момент?

Пример некорректного отправления в строку состояния координат курсора.

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        POINT pt;
        GetCursorPos(&pt);
        ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
        x = pt.x;
        y = pt.y;
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 1, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
    }
```

[Проект](https://docviewer.yandex.ru/view/273467293/?*=LWWDhlJoXuBPrmJGwe%2FRJFJJ%2BKF7InVybCI6InlhLWRpc2s6Ly8vZGlzay%2FQo9GH0LXQsdCwL2xhYmE1X29zLjd6IiwidGl0bGUiOiJsYWJhNV9vcy43eiIsInVpZCI6IjI3MzQ2NzI5MyIsInl1IjoiMjI5MzE3NjExNTAzNjg3NDI0Iiwibm9pZnJhbWUiOmZhbHNlLCJ0cyI6MTUwNDAyNTc4NDE3NH0%3D)

Comment: Без понимания какое именно сообщение вы шлете ваш вопрос не имеет смысла, IMHO. А с пониманием нужно лезть в MSDN и спрашивать после прочтения оного конкретные вопросы.

Comment: Необходимо создать строку состояние и отправить туда то, что описано выше.
Ниже приведен код, но работает неккоректно...
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
 {
  POINT pt;
  GetCursorPos(&pt);
  ScreenToClient(hWnd, &pt);
  x = pt.x;
  y = pt.y;
  PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MOUSEMOVE, 1, MAKELPARAM(x, y));
 }

Comment: Что есть "работает некорректно" - не ясно. Надеюсь, вы понимаете что вы отправляете сообщение о перемещении мыши с зажатой левой кнопкой (и лучше использовать MK_LBUTTON)? И понимаете ли вы, что вы передаете те же координаты для перемещения, на которых курсор и так находится?

Comment: Некорректно - значит не работает. 1) Да 2) Да

Comment: А чего вы ожидаете? Вы шлете окну буквально следующее: "По тебе переместился курсор мыши на 0 пикселей в каждую сторону". Подозреваю, что нулевое перемещение легко может игнорироваться, потому что перемещения нет. Попробуйте реальное перемещение задать

Comment: Попробовал, молчок.

Comment: Непонятно, чего Вы хотите сделать: что за "отобразить в sendmessage координаты курсора" и "создать строку состояние и отправить туда то, что описано выше"? Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: Доброе утро, необходимо создать строку состояния с отображением координат и отображением пункта меню,на котором стоит курсор. Как я понял для отправки каких-либо данных в строку состояния используется функции sendmessgae,postmessage и т.д.(возможно). Поправьте меня, если я не прав. Спасибо.

Comment: А, ну вот, так уже понятнее. Тогда уточните, какой компонент Вы используете. Существует [стандартный компонент](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298378(v=vs.85).aspx). Чтобы отобразить на нем произвольный текст, необходимо передать его в сообщении SB_SETTEXT. Вот [пример](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/163311-microsoft-working-with-status-bars/).

Comment: Статус бар я уже создал, не получается передать координаты курсора. Как это сделать?)

Comment: Пробовал так: SendMessage(hwndSb, SB_SETTEXT, 1, (LPARAM)&(pt.x, pt.y));

Comment: Подскажет кто?(((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
    {
        int x = (short)LOWORD(lParam);
        int y = (short)HIWORD(lParam);
        std::string text = std::to_string(x) + ":" + std::to_string(y);
        SendMessage(hwndSb, SB_SETTEXTA, 1, (LPARAM)text.c_str());
        break;
    }
```

- [архив с проектом](https://www.dropbox.com/s/uw039wovhp147yj/so-711273.zip?dl=0)
- [готовый exe](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a0y7zo6m6lfu1gc/so-711273.exe?dl=0) (если не страшно)

Comment: Спасибо, не работает, но очень похоже на правду, мне кажется нужно отправить sendmessage с обработкой wm_mousemove?

Comment: код рабочий, приложил проект + exe

Comment: Главный пост, ссылка Проект на яндекс диск

Comment: проверьте ссылку, у меня не получилось по ней загрузить проект

Comment: Главный косяк оказался в том, что hwndSb не был статичным...

Comment: Поэтому предоставленный Вами case не работал как надо. Спасибо:)

Comment: `hwndSb` может быть не статичным: если присвоить этому компоненту `ID`, то hwndSb можно получить через `GetDlgItem`, или можно сразу по ID послать сообщение, через `SendDlgItemMessage`. Чтобы присвоить этому компоненту ID надо его передать в `HMENU` при создании окна.